The angle of the prism for which there is no emergent ray will be, if its critical angle is $i_c$?
I read the answer here https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-angle-of-the-prism-for-which-there-is-no-emergent-ray-will-be-if/ . It said applying Snell's law at the two refracting surfaces,
$\sin i= \mu \sin r$
$\sin e = \mu \sin r_2.$
Also,
$A = r_1+r_2.$
For no emergent ray,
$e = 90^o,$
hence,
$r_2 = i c.$
Also, for there to be no emergent ray in any case, $r_1$ can have the maximum value in the limiting case.
For this to happen,
$i=90^o$
in this case. Hence
$$r_1= i c$$
so,
$$A>2ic.$$ I don't understand why it is said for there to be no emerging ray in any case $A>2ic.$ Shouldn't just $r_2 \geq 1/ug$ for there to be no emerging ray ($ug$ is the refractive index of the prism)? Why do you have to make the angle of incidence go 90 degrees? It should not matter no matter how many rays pass through as long as $r_2 \geq 1/ug,$ right?  (I got this equation $r_2 \geq 1/ug$ as $ug\sin r_2 = u \sin e.$) For there to be no emerging ray, $e$ must be equal to or greater than 90 degrees.

Your wording is confusing, but here's the basic answer:  at some point, to get the equalities in the first two equations, you'll need  one of the sin() values to go negative, which is of course impossible.

You are right. There is an error in the linked answer.
The first two equations should be:
$\sin(i) = \mu \sin(r1) $
$\sin(e) = 1/\mu \sin(r2) $
The ratio  $\mu = (N2/N1)$ has to be inverted for the second equation because in that case the ray is moving from the high refractive index material of the prism to the lower refractive index of the air outside. While it is true that r1+r2 = A as claimed, I think they have also made the false assumption that r1=r2, which is not correct.
This system of equations can be solved for the critical angle of (i) where the final ray does not emerge from the prism. The result is not simple. The critical angle of i is a function of both A and $\mu$.
Check out this Ray tracing GeoGebra app (New improved!). The incident angle (i), the apex angle of the prism (A) and the refractive index ratio $(u) = N2/N1$ can be varied using the sliders. (The dashed red ray is the internally reflected ray off the second surface)

